# Transact SQL: how to create double sided foreign key constraints?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, foreign-keys

Say I have two tables: `A` and `B`

`A` has one column which is a primary key on `B`, i.e., a foreign key and `B` has one column which is a primary key on `A`, i.e., a foreign key.

So I would do

```
CREATE TABLE A(
 idA INT PRIMARY KEY,
 idB INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES B(idB)
);

CREATE TABLE B(
 idB INT PRIMARY KEY,
 idA INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES A(idA)
);
```

and would expect it to work; however, the sql server management studio gives me the following error:
`Foreign key references invalid table for table B`
If I swap their order, the error will be in the table `A` instead.

How do I overcome this issue, given that I have a double sided relationships, i.e., `A` references `B` and `B` references `A`.

Comment: Try creating the tables first, then adding the FK after the tables are created (because you are trying to create a key on a table that doesnt exist yet when you create table A

Comment: I have an assignment that needs a single script with all the create table's information. Is there not a way to do it?

Comment: You can't reference a table you haven't created yet (or Patterson the batch). SQL is sequential so the second table won't exist when you run the first statement. Create both, then use an `ALTER TABLE` statement to add both constraints with a non-default name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to do the first constraint with a separate `ALTER TABLE`, because the reference table has not yet been defined.  SQL has no concept of a "forward reference" in this case.

```
CREATE TABLE A (
 idA INT PRIMARY KEY,
 idB INT
);

CREATE TABLE B (
 idB INT PRIMARY KEY,
 idA INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES A(idA)

);

ALTER TABLE A
    ADD CONSTRAINT FK_A_B FOREIGN KEY (idB) REFERENCES B(idB);
```

Some database designers have the habit of doing *all* foreign key constraints after the table definitions so they don't have to worry about the order the table definitions.

They usually arrive at this pattern after adding a new foreign key somewhere and watching a script fail because of the ordering of the table declarations.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=83db4e04d7f7946541487663d714db0c) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: If you may, what is the `FK_B_A`.

Comment: @DuarteArribas . . . It is the name of the constraint.  You will find that the built-in names are rather inscrutible.

Comment: If this answers the question, @DuarteArribas , you should accept it as the solution.

Answer (score 2):

So, I see people are going to answer this without asking the obvious question:

Why the circular reference?

Perhaps there is some brilliant design I am missing, but the idea you FK a PK on one table and then do the converse seems like REALLY bad design. I am open to learning, but it sounds like a disaster.

In general:

- With one-to-many, one table is a parent, or lookup, and the other has an FK to that table
- With one-to-one, you normally dupe the ID (subclass) so there can be only one in each table. Or, you redesign and create a single table.
- You can constrain, via other means, but you still have a circular concept in your schema

Your abstract "here is what I am doing" is not real world enough for me to suggest a better way of achieving your actual business goal, rather than simply telling you how to do something I see will likely be a train wreck one day.

Comment: Assignments, unfortunately/annoyingly/stupidly/etc, often set unrealistic and arbitrary requirements. I wouldn't be surprised bthisnis one of them.

Comment: @Larnu - My big issue is when someone asks "how do I hit crash my car at 90 miles an hour with no seatbelt and not die" and someone actually answers the question rather than asking "what are you trying to accomplish?" When they say "I want to impress my girlfriend", the proper answer is "buy her flowers" not "pad yourself with pillows"