# How to Handle the Relationship?

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have a database table like this. The issue I'm facing is how to create a page when there is no page_admin yet. Because I need to create a page first to have its value to create a page_admin. I'm using Laravel, and my idea is when I create a page, how can I trick the page - page_admin relationship to be null, and then proceed to create a page_admin and assign the page_admin's id back to the page - page_admin. Please help me. (NO DATABASE ALTERATION :>)

````
PAGE | page_id: bigInt, PK, NOT NULL, AUTO_INCREMENT (Page ID)
page_admin: int, FK, NOT NULL, references id in table page_admin (Page Administrator ID)
page_category: int, FK, NOT NULL, references id in table pages_categories (Category ID)
page_name: varchar(255), NOT NULL, UNIQUE (Page URL. Example: nguyenthanhson => https://localhost/pages/nguyenthanhson)
page_title: varchar(255), NOT NULL (Page Title)
page_verified: enum(0, 1), NOT NULL, DEFAULT(0) (Page Verification Status. Verified: 1, Not Verified: 0)
page_company: varchar(256), NULL (Company Name of the Page)
page_phone: varchar(256), NULL (Phone Number of the Page)
page_website: mediumtext, NULL (Website URL of the Page)
page_address: varchar(256), NULL (Office Address of the Page)
page_description: mediumtext, NOT NULL (Page Description)
page_likes: int, NOT NULL, DEFAULT(0) (Number of Page Likes)
page_date: timestamps, NOT NULL (Page Creation Timestamp)
Table: pages_admin

PAGE_ADMIN | id: bigInt, PK, NOT NULL, AUTO_INCREMENT (Admin ID)
page_id: int, FK, NOT NULL, references page_id in table pages (Page ID)
user_id: int, FK, NOT NULL, references id in table users (User ID)
Table: pages_categories

PAGE_CATEGORY | category_id: bigInt, PK, NOT NULL, AUTO_INCREMENT (Category ID)
category_parent_id: int, FK, NOT NULL, references id in table pages_categories (Parent Category ID)
category_name: varchar(256), NOT NULL (Category Name)
category_description: text, NOT NULL (Category Description)
category_order: int, NOT NULL (Category Order) ```
````

Comment: Is there a reason why not to use migration to create the tables? Also if you want to use a `NOT NULL` for your page admin, you can use default: https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/mysql_default.asp

Comment: If you dont want db alterations then create the page first with a dummy page_admin value during create. Create your page admin and set the pk value to the page->page_admin

Comment: There is not good advice to be given if you want no database alterations your design is pretty much breaking the database design standards For example if you have pages_categories table you don't need a page_admin column on pages_admin to find admins

read about SQL LEFT JOINs and Joins in general to help you with better design

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Transact SQL: how to create double sided foreign key constraints?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65240231/transact-sql-how-to-create-double-sided-foreign-key-constraints)